# Partially match strings in case of List.contains(String)

Tags: java, regex

I have a `List<String>`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("ABCD");
list.add("EFGH");
list.add("IJ KL");
list.add("M NOP");
list.add("UVW X");
```

if I do `list.contains("EFGH")`, it returns `true`.
Can I get a true in case of `list.contains("IJ")`? I mean, can I partially match strings to find if they exist in the list?

I have a list of 15000 strings. And I have to check about 10000 strings if they exist in the list. What could be some other (faster) way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: *"Can I get a `true` in case of `list.contains("IJ")`?"*  What happened when you *tried* it?

Comment: do you have to know *which exact* term it matches, or is it enough to know just that it matches one of your terms (without knowing which one)?

Comment: list.stream().anyMatch("yourstring"::contains)

Comment: Mahi: Did you even try you own answer? That doesn't work differently from .contains() at all.

Answer (score 5):

If suggestion from Roadrunner-EX does not suffice then, I believe you are looking for [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

Time complexity:

- Time complexity of the table algorithm is O(n), preprocessing time
- Time complexity of the search algorithm is O(k)

So, the complexity of the overall algorithm is O(n + k).

- n = Size of the List
- k = length of pattern you are searching for

Normal Brute-Force will have time complexity of O(nm)

Moreover KMP algorithm will take same O(k) complexity for searching with same search string, on the other hand, it will be always O(km) for brute force approach.

Comment: What's m in O(nm) and O(km)? Also, check out my simple O(k) solution below.  Why won't that work?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you want to put each String group into a HashSet, and by fragment, I mean don't add "IJ KL" but rather add "IJ" and "KL" separately.  If you need both the list and this search capabilities, you may need to maintain two collections.

Comment: A sort of suffix array.

Answer (score 4):

As a second answer, upon rereading your question, you could also inherit from the interface `List`, specialize it for `Strings` only, and override the contains() method.

```
public class PartialStringList extends ArrayList<String>
{
    public boolean contains(Object o)
    {
        if(!(o instanceof String))
        {
            return false;
        }
        String s = (String)o;
        Iterator<String> iter = iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            String iStr = iter.next();
            if (iStr.contain(s))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Judging by your earlier comments, this is maybe not the speed you're looking for, but is this more similar to what you were asking for?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [IterableUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IterableUtils.html) from [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("ABCD");
list.add("EFGH");
list.add("IJ KL");
list.add("M NOP");
list.add("UVW X");

boolean hasString = IterableUtils.contains(list, "IJ", new Equator<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean equate(String o1, String o2) {
        return o2.contains(o1);
    }

    @Override
    public int hash(String o) {
        return o.hashCode();
    }
});

System.out.println(hasString); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list, and then call contains() on each String.

```
public boolean listContainsString(List<string> list. String checkStr)
{
    Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        String s = iter.next();
        if (s.contain(checkStr))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Something like that should work, I think.

Comment: This is what I am doing right now. But this will give me a false if I want to partially match. Also with this I will have to iterate through 15000 entries 10000 times.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question then. I'm pretty sure this will return true on partial match, as you requested, though it's late here so I maybe completely missing a bug in tiredness. Also, as Hovercraft suggests, do you know if they'll be separated in anyway (with a space or another character)? If so, that would make the problem easier.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
java.util.List<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
list.add("ABCD");
list.add("EFGH");
list.add("IJ KL");
list.add("M NOP");
list.add("UVW X");
java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("IJ");
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher("");
for(String s : list)
{
    m.reset(s);
    if(m.find()) System.out.println("Partially Matched");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that uses a regex to shortcut the inner loop if *none* of the test Strings are found in the target String.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> haystack = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ABCD", "EFGH", "IJ KL", "M NOP", "UVW X" });
    List<String> needles = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "IJ", "NOP" });

    // To cut down on iterations, create one big regex to check the whole haystack
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(".*(");
    for (String needle : needles) {
        sb.append(needle).append('|');
    }
    sb.replace(sb.length() - 1, sb.length(), ").*");
    String regex = sb.toString();

    for (String target : haystack) {
        if (!target.matches(regex)) {
            System.out.println("Skipping " + target);
            continue;
        }

        for (String needle : needles) {
            if (target.contains(needle)) {
                System.out.println(target + " contains " + needle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Skipping ABCD
Skipping EFGH
IJ KL contains IJ
M NOP contains NOP
Skipping UVW X
```

If you really want to get cute, you could bisect use a binary search to identify which segments of the target list matches, but it mightn't be worth it.

It depends which is how likely it is that yo'll find a hit. Low hit rates will give a good result. High hit rates will perform not much better than the simple nested loop version. consider inverting the loops if some needles hit many targets, and other hit none.

It's all about aborting a search path ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! Sort of.

What you are looking for, is often called [*fuzzy searching* or *approximate string matching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) and there are several solutions to this problem.

With the [FuzzyWuzzy](https://github.com/xdrop/fuzzywuzzy) lib, for example, you can have all your strings assigned a score based on how similar they are to a particular search term. The actual values seem to be integer percentages of the number of characters matching with regards to the search string length.

After invoking `FuzzySearch.extractAll`, it is up to you to decide what the minimum score would be for a string to be considered a match.

There are also other, similar libraries worth checking out, like [google-diff-match-patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) or the [Apache Commons Text Similarity API](https://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/similarity/package-summary.html), and so on.

If you need something really heavy-duty, your best bet would probably be [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) (as also mentioned by [Ryan Shillington](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20822180/1763363))

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the given problem. But I guess this answer will help someone to compare partially both given and the elements in a list using [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).

```
final Equator equator = new Equator<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean equate(String o1, String o2) {
            final int i1 = o1.lastIndexOf(":");
            final int i2 = o2.lastIndexOf(":");
            return o1.substring(0, i1).equals(o2.substring(0, i2));
        }

        @Override
        public int hash(String o) {
            final int i1 = o.lastIndexOf(":");
            return o.substring(0, i1).hashCode();
        }
    };
    final List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("a1:v1", "a2:v2");
    System.out.println(IteratorUtils.matchesAny(list.iterator(), new EqualPredicate("a2:v1", equator)));
```