# Find substring in List and return Index Number

Tags: java, arrays, list, substring

I have an List, with Strings like:

```
String One
String Two
String Three
```

Now i would like to get the Index Number for the Substring "One". How can i get this?
I only could make it if i convert it to an Array and then:

```
public static int findInArray(Object[] arr, String searchName) {
int i;
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++ ) { 
    String test = arr[i].toString();
    if (test.contains(searchName)) {
        //System.out.println("Substring found in:"+i);
        break;
    }
}
return i;
}
```

Isn't there a way to search for the Substring without converting it to an Array?

Comment: You can use List instead of array here.

Comment: Another thing you should consider is how you phrase your contains check. To continue from your example above, if you have a list with elements ["String Twenty-One", "String Two", "String Three"], your code will find the substring "One" in index 0, which may not be what you want. This might be a bit of a contrived example, but the point still holds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645379/partially-match-strings-in-case-of-list-containsstring

Comment: @AndreaLigios I also saw this Question you linked, but there wasn't the Answer i was searching for.

Comment: There are three interesting answers: you can create your own implementation of an ArrayList<String>, or you can "tokenize" your values WHILE inserting them, or you can use KMP search applied to a loop through elements. Or you can do like in the accepted answer here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*List already contains indexes*

```
 for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i){
     if (list.get(i).contains("searchString")) {
         System.out.println("Substring found in:"+i);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int find(List<String> list, String searchString) {
    for(int i=0 ; i < list.size() ; ++i){
        if (list.get(i).contains(searchString)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way, and you can get its index, or return -1 indicating not found.

```
public static int findInList(List<String> list, String searchName) {
    for(String str : list){
        if(str.indexOf(searchName) > -1){
          //System.out.println("Substring found in:"+i);
              return list.indexOf(str);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: That's identical to an answer below, except it's worse: while doing a cute for-each iteration you're forcing an additional expensive "indexOf" for no reason

Comment: @iluxa String.contains(CharSequence) actually calls String.indexOf(String) too.

Comment: str.indexOf() is fine. i'm talking about list.indexOf() you're using.

Comment: @iluxa I got your point, maybe next time I need to think about more about performance issue when post the code.