# Contains not finding partial string in List or Set

Tags: java, collections, contains

I currently have a Set that contains three strings (`"car"`, `"two dollar"`, `"foo"`). I then execute the following against a passed `HashMap<String, Double>`.

```
if (getSet().contains(currentHashMapItem.getKey()) == true) {
    System.out.println(currentHashMapItem.getKey());
}
```

The first key is `"car"`, that matches as expected and displays. However, the second key is `"dollar"`, but doesn't display. Now my understanding of how contains works is it will return true if the string it is comparing exists in the Set that's being returned in `getSet()`, but no dice. Even tried an `ArrayList<String>` as well with no luck. Anyone ran into this before? Am I trying to cut too sharp a corner and forced to use a regex or iterator loop?

Comment: contains() uses equals(). And "dollar" is clearly not equal to "two dollar". So that's expected. Read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: @JBNizet dammit I knew it was something simple I was overlooking. Thanks JB.

Comment: You might want to look into this thread as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645379/partially-match-strings-in-case-of-list-containsstring

Comment: BTW `==true` is redundant, and in most cases provides risk of making mistake like `while(variable = true)` where instead of `==` we use `=` which is assignment, not comparison, causing infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Set` does not contain "dollar" but "two dollar". Therefore it contains a string which contains the key but does not directly contain the key. As the `Set.contains()` method [uses `.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29), this will fail unless the keys are identical.

You can iterate through the set of keys and see if any `String.contains()` your key.

As an additional option, you could make a new `Set` class with your own `contains()` method (either overriding or overloading the current one) which uses the `String.contains()` method of comparison instead of `.equals()`. This could be done three ways:

**Implement the `Set` interface**
-Convenient and could simply overload the `boolean contains(Object)` method with a `boolean contains(String)` option (also look at using the `AbstractSet` class)

**[Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition)**
-Allows use of a distinct type of `Set` (such as `HashSet`, `TreeSet`, etc), instead of the more general interface

**Inheritence**
-Similar to composition but a less elegant and appropriate option
-Only do this if you have other reasons to want a child class

Comment: Composition would be a better option instead of extending from Set.

Comment: If you are implementing `Set`, that's not a problem. My comment was for extending from a concrete `Set` implementation because your answer said *you could create a child class of Set*

Comment: @CKing does the `Set` interface not already have an implementation for `contains()`? I'm assuming you'd have to do something more than just implementing the interface to get a custom `contains()` method.

Comment: What I am saying is basically : `class SetPartialContains implements Set { private Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(); public boolean contains(String o) { for(String s : set) { if(s.contains(o)) return true; } } }`

Comment: @CKing ah, I would've thought that would throw an error as `boolean contains(Object)` already has an implementation in `Set`. But I suppose that it can be overloaded by taking a `String` parameter instead.

Comment: @CKing I've added all 3 options to my answer, with some info on the pro and cons of each. I do think the implementation of the interface looks easiest though. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Went with this answer as I felt it was the most complete and descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

The key is "two dollar".  That does not match "dollar" so the key is not found.  To do what you want, you would have to retrieve every key in the set, and use `keyString.contains("dollar");` to look for partial matches.

Answer (score 1):

The `contains` method will use the `equals` method of `String` class which looks for an exact match. Therefore, `"dollar".equals("two dollar");` will return false.

What you want to do is iterate through the `Set` and use `String.contains` instead :

```
Set<String> set = getSet();
for(String s : set) {
  if(currentHashMapItem.getKey().contains(s)) {
     System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`contains` returns `true` if the collection (in your case - a `Set`) contains the object passed to it. Your set does not contain the string `"dollar"` - it contains a longer string,  `"two dollars"`. If you want to test whether a collection contains a given substring, you'd have to implement it yourself:

```
public static boolean containsSubString (Collection<String> col, String str) {
    for (String s: col) {
        if (s.contains(str)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

contains on Set is true if key is **equal** to the parameter

contains on String is true if string contains parameter

Comment: `getSet()` seems to return a `Set` and not a `Map`

Comment: @CKing thanks, missed that for some reason, was quite obvious it was a Set :D