# Check if List <String> contains substring

Tags: java, android, list

I'm developing an Android app where I get a List of names (Strings) from a SQLite database. Then, I show them on a List of Cardviews.

I'm also given a substring, so I'd like to check if any of the elements of the original List  contains that substring on it.

I'm having problems using LIKE in the SQLite query, so I've just fixed it with a `try{ } catch (Exception e) { }`, but I don't feel so comfortable with it.

Anyway, since I originally have all of the names stored in the List of Strings, I don't really need to fecth the new ones again from the database, I can just search them on the original List of Strings. But I don't know how.

For example, let's say the List of String has this 5 elements:

`Hello`
`Wall`
`Helicopter`
`Chair`
`Hell`

And I'm given the substring `Hel`. I should get the `Hello`, `Helicopter` and `Hell` strings, since all of them contain the substring `Hel`.

Any ideas on how to achieve this goal?

It's not that I want to fix it this way. I sincerely would like to know **what's the most efficient,** if retrieveing the data again from the database, or search it from the List of Strings.

EDIT: I originally said that I was using the CONTAINS query, but I missed the word. I just meant the LIKE query. I'm actually using it, and it works fine but I don't really know what's the most efficient in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My fault. I'm actually using the LIKE query. I missed the word when I said contains. I edited the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partially match strings in case of List.contains(String)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645379/partially-match-strings-in-case-of-list-containsstring)

Comment: so whats wrong with Like query? DB would optimize the search based on index which would be much faster than doing that yourself with a foreach loop

Comment: Searching list in memory is definitely more efficient that running another query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

```
public boolean isSubstring(String str, String key) {
    if(key.length() > str.length()) return false;
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= str.length() - key.length(); i++) {
        if( key.equals(str.substring(i, i + key.length())) ) return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}

public List<String> findStings(List<String> list, String key) {
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if(isSubstring(list.get(i), key)) {
            newList.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
    
    return newList;
}
```

If you are working with Java 8 you can replace the for-loop of the second method as:

```
for(String str: list) {
    if(isSubstring(str, key)) newList.add(str);
}
```

or simply as:

```
list.stream().filter((str) -> (isSubstring(str, key))).forEach((str) -> { newList.add(str); });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Java 8:

```
List<String> filteredList = myList.stream().filter(s -> s.contains("Hel")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you're using anything earlier, use a `for` each loop:

```
List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s : myList)
    if(s.contains("Hel")
        filteredList.add(s);
```